# No queries found by pgbadger on Fedora

Tags: pgbadger

When run with this command, pgbadger finds no queries, even though there are slow queries logged in the database log.

```
pgbadger --dbname foo  /path/to/logfile --format stderr --prefix '%m [%p] '
```

Example log entry

```
2020-04-08 07:58:42.014 BST [1505890] LOG:  duration: 119.079 ms  statement: SELECT "bar".id FROM "bar" WHERE (("bar"."baz" = 0.0)  AND  ("bar"."quux" = 0.0)) ORDER BY "bar"."id"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was passing the  `--dbname` flag and its argument.  The log prefix `'%m [%p] '` does not include the database name, so `pgbadger`, presumably, is unable to find any statements logged against the provided database name and reports accordingly.

The solution is to either not pass `--dbname` or modify the log prefix in `postgresql.conf` to include the database name (for example `'%m [%p] %d '`), reload the server config and wait for new entries in the log.

I found this on an Openstack Fedora vm, where `'%m [%p] '` was the default log prefix.